# Get payload value of an XBee packet on Arduino UNO r3

Tags: java, arduino, xbee

I'm working on a project that using XBee S1 as a transmitter / receiver. These are the hardware I am using:

1. Coordinator: XBee USB EXplorer v2.0 with XBee S1 Modules
2. End Devices: [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) r3.0 with XBee [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) and XBee S1 Modules

The purpose of the project is simple, that is to turn on / off the [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode). And here is the code (controller):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws XBeeException,
                                       InterruptedException {
    XBee xbee = new XBee();
    boolean running = true;
    try {
        // OPEN SERIAL PORT
        xbee.open("COM10", 9600); // String arg is
                                  // Unique to YOUR
                                  // MACHINE!

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        XBeeAddress16 address = new XBeeAddress16(0x22, 0x22);
        int[] payload;
        payload = new int[1];

        System.out.println("Enter a new command for LED: 0 to turn the LED OFF, 1 to turn ON");
        payload[0] = (int) input.nextByte();

        TxRequest64 request = new TxRequest64(address, payload);

        System.out.println("\nXBee request is: " + request.getXBeePacket());

        while (running) {
            try {
                TxStatusResponse response = (TxStatusResponse) xbee
                        .sendSynchronous(request, 100);
                request.setFrameId(xbee.getNextFrameId());

                System.out.println("\nXBee request is: " + request.getXBeePacket());

                System.out.println("Response received" + response);

                if (response.getApiId() != ApiId.TX_STATUS_RESPONSE)
                {
                    System.out.println("Response error");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Response success");
                }
            }
            catch (XBeeTimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println("Me ! Unable to send");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter a new command for LED: 0 to turn the LED OFF, 1 to turn ON");
            payload[0] = (int) input.nextByte();
            request.setPayload(payload);
            if(payload[0] == 2)
                running = false;
        }
    }
    finally {
        xbee.close();
    }
}
```

And this is the code for Arduino (end device):

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
int LED = 12;                //Turn this LED on or off, depending on packet rx'd
int debugLED = 13;           //Flash light to indicate rx
int packet;                 //Packet will be two bytes in length
int analogValue;
int debugValue = 0;
int discard;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(debugLED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  packet = 0x01;
  lcd.begin(16,2);
}

void loop() {
 lcd.setCursor(0, 1); 
 if(Serial.available() >= 16){     //<--Changing the value from 21 to 16 fixed the problem! 

    debugValue = 0;

    debugValue = Serial.read();

    if(debugValue == 0x7e){      //Look for starting byte
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(debugValue);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(debugLED, HIGH);    //Flash Arduino LED (not the one on digital pin 11)
      delay(1000);                          //to indicate rx'ing data
      digitalWrite(debugLED, LOW);
      //lcd.print(debugValue);


      for(int i = 2; i != 10; i++){      //Discard unused data (see XBee API protocol for more info)
        discard = Serial.read();
        if (i != 8)
          packet = discard;
          // print the number of seconds since reset:
         if(i == 5)
         lcd.setCursor(0,1);
         lcd.print(packet);
         delay(500);
      }
      lcd.print(discard);
   }
 }
 if(packet == 0x7e)
     digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
 else
     digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}
```

The problem is the output in the LCD display always shows same output. How could that be?

These are the '**strange**' numbers I got from LCD:

```
126 0 6 129 125 49 125 49 125 125 29 29
```

Those values remains the same, tough I've changed the input value from 0 to 1!!

This is the sample output from my Java terminal (console):

```
1

XBee request is: 0x7e,0x00,0x06,0x01,0x02,0x22,0x22,0x00,0x01,0xb7
Response receivedapiId=TX_STATUS_RESPONSE (0x89),length=3,checksum=0x75,error=false,frameId=0x01,status=SUCCESS
Response success
Enter a new command for LED: 0 to turn the LED OFF, 1 to turn on
0

XBee request is: 0x7e,0x00,0x06,0x01,0x03,0x22,0x22,0x00,0x00,0xb7
Response receivedapiId=TX_STATUS_RESPONSE (0x89),length=3,checksum=0x74,error=false,frameId=0x02,status=SUCCESS
Response success
Enter a new command for LED: 0 to turn the LED OFF, 1 to turn on
```

I'm sure this is the payload value (marked with ^^^^):

```
0x7e,0x00,0x06,0x01,0x02,0x22,0x22,0x00,0x01,0xb7
                                        ^^^^
```

But how to get that value with Arduino?

Anyway, I referenced to the tutorial *[XBee API Project One](https://sites.google.com/site/enginerdextraordinaire/the-team/java-project/xbee-api-project-one)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after doing some search, the best way to get XBee's payload value through Arduino is using [XBee API for Arduino](http://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/), as I read this site: [wirelessly transmit analog signals using the Arduino XBee API](http://kavasmlikon.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/how-to-wirelessly-transmit-analog-signals-using-the-arduino-xbee-api/). Here is the code to get the 'payload' value:

```
#include<Xbee.h>
int DEBUG = 13;
XBee xbee = XBee();
XBeeResponse response = XBeeResponse();
Rx16Response rx16 = Rx16Response();

void setup() {
  pinMode(DEBUG, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  DEBUG = 0;
}

void loop() {
 xbee.readPacket();

 if(xbee.getResponse().isAvailable()){
   lcd.print("Data received");
     if(xbee.getResponse().getApiId() == RX_16_RESPONSE){
       xbee.getResponse().getRx16Response(rx16);

       uint8_t payload = rx16.getData(0);//this is the payload value, easy to get it :D
     }
 }     
}
```

That is!! :D